# Replace '^M`(crlf) with '\n'(lf) (new line) in a cloned git repo to get correct git blame?

Tags: git, github

So I have cloned a github repo and I am running the command `git show <revision_id>:<file_path>`, I am getting the output something like this -
[image] and when I run `git blame` on the file it says that the file doesn't have enough lines.

I know it has something to do with Windows using crlf for new line and Unix based operating system using lf. I went through [this](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) link , but I think this is something that should be done at the time of repo initialisation or commit. Is there any way to get new lines intead of ^M after cloning the repo (maybe a flag that can be used with git(show/blame) command or something else) ?

Thanks

Comment: ^M is only a representation (of CR; CARRIAGE RETURN; \r). It is not a literal "^M". See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it

Comment: Yes I know , So I want "\n" instead of "^M" because when I do a git blame on a specific , it says the file doesn't have enough lines as it replaces the new lines with "^M" and compresses all the lines

Comment: If you know then, at the very least, the question would be phrased differently..

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/ and questions about such. For a one-time conversion see dos2unix.

Comment: Already mentioned in the description "I know it has ...... "